# passing parameter from .php file to .js file

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing

how do i call an array from a php file to a .js file?

so far i have this in my functions.php.

```
function background(){

  global $post;
  $bgsrc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'background', true);
   if($bgsrc != null){
    $bgsrc = explode("\n", $bgsrc);
    $ctr=0;
    foreach($bgsrc as $value){ ?> 
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" class="bgimgsrc" id="bgimgsrc-<?php echo $ctr++; ?>" >
    <?php }
   }
 }
```

on my .js file i have this but its not working..

```
function backgroundsizer(){
 var ctr= {image:jQuery('.bgimgsrc').val()}

 jQuery.supersized({
  // Functionality
  slide_interval          :   10000,  // Length between transitions
  transition              :   1,    // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
  transition_speed  : 900,  // Speed of transition

  // Components       
  slide_links    : 'blank', // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
  slides      :   ctr

 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function backgroundsizer(){
  var valArr = new Array();
  jQuery(".bgimgsrc").each(function() {
    valArr.push(jQuery(this).val());
  });
  //you will have values in "valArr" array, you can manipulate it, like
  var joinedVals = valArr.join(","); // just an example
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks! i replaced :  `valArr.push(jQuery(this).val());` with  `valarr.push({image : jQuery(this).val() });` and it worked like a charm:)

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the php variable directly from javascript. if you want to use the values then you have to make js variables using php values on run time

```
<?php
$weight = 10;
?>
<script>
var weight = <?php echo $weight;?>;
alert(weight);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider requesting data from PHP using jQuery, via an AJAX request for example.
That data can then be parsed and used accordingly.

It might work something like this:

1. jQuery send a request to a PHP script, using AJAX.
2. The PHP script returns the data requested, in this case an array, which could be expressed as a string with its elements separated
3. jQuery receives the string and parses it to an array, to achieve this, you can use regular expressions.

Hope this helps. Have a great day.